# How to disassembe a IKEA Mammut Stool?

Tags: self-assembly-furniture

I have a [Mammut stool](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/mammut-childrens-stool-indoor-outdoor-yellow-20382324/) that my family member use it for bathing so it is full of water inside. However, it is well structured so it doesn't seems to leak so easily, if shake the chair will hear a lot of water inside, I want to disassembly it to release the water.

I have tried to investigate the structure of the leg or other chair in the same series but still cannot detach the leg.

Does any one know how to do it?

Edit: 2022/2/15
It is the [link](https://www.ikea.com.hk/en/products/small-children-(3-7)/childrens-desks-and-chairs-(3-7)/mammut-art-50382327) for the stool product page (mine is green but I think it should be the same)

I have tried to contact local IKEA CS, they just reply with a link to the [manual](https://www.ikea.com.hk/dairyfarm/hk/pdfs/assembly/en/992/AA-70992-4_pub.pdf) and the manual did not provide any clue for detachment.

Because the link might be changed in the future, so I try to put some specific images here for reference. This is the same color as my stool.
[image: Stool image]

While this image is from the manual P.3-4.
[image: Mammut stool partial manual]

Comment: Since it's used for bathing, drill drain holes at the bottom.

Comment: Since water is getting in through _somewhere_ it should be able to come out through those same places. Have you tried tipping/turning it to see if the water will leak out? It probably won't gush out, but it may _slowly_ leak out - remember, it's sitting in water for 10+ minutes for the bath, so it will take at least that long for water to start leaking back out. Additionally, pics of your stool (or at least a link to IKEA's page and a pic or two borrowed from there) will help people get a feel for what you're dealing with.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for taking time, I have collected the image and manual and put them into the question together. After observing several days, like what you said, it is not gushing out. It only leaks for some positions or shaking it. So the water saving could only possibly be drying out if not manually doing something on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a plastic stool. Unless the legs are solid plastic (in which case water wouldn't be getting into them), simply drill a small hole at the bottom of each leg. This will allow the water to drain back out, probably more quickly than it's leaking in now.

Depending on how flat the bottoms of the feet and your tub are, you may want to define a "tip direction" by drilling the holes all on the same bottom corner of the legs. This way, you can tip the stool so all the holes are at their lowest point, allowing the water to quickly run out without the resistance of hitting the bottom of the tub. Most tubs (that I've seen) have some sort of texturing on the bottom to help make them less slippery, so this probably won't be a concern.

Comment: Adding a small vent hole near the tops of the legs and hidden below the seat would help with the drainage.

Comment: Good point, @HABO. However, since water seems to be leaking in effectively without additional venting, it should also escape reasonably effectively without it. Add a _small_ hole near the top of each leg _if necessary_.

Comment: I am not sure if the leg is hollow or not but I am pretty sure the sitting base composed of 2 pieces. While shaking it, I could feel the water mainly staying in the sitting base portion. While shaking, there is very little water leaking out at the hole of connection between the leg and the base Adding venting hole will damage or not, I am not sure. I could see that from the manual, the leg seems using a reverse locking mechanism that the head of the leg injecting into the hole of the base is thicker, so after the "click" sound, it locked inside with the base closely locked itself too.

Comment: Whatever the attachment method, @simongcc, the plastic, of the legs or seat, has a hole in it somewhere that's allowing water in during the bath but not allowing it back out fast enough for your satisfaction. Your goal is to get the water back out. Disassembling the stool is not likely to expose those holes that the water is leaking in through, so make a bigger drain hole somewhere in the stool, preferably somewhere low and not immediately obvious. If you're also (only) getting water in the seat, you'll need to make a drain in the seat somewhere, too.

Comment: I think your method is sensible. But end up I have leaved it alone without using it. It almost dried out naturally. LOL. I simply don't want to use any intrusive method. This stool is designed to be assembled without dissembling mechanism probably for the endurability sake.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. I had the same issue.  Water stay inside the stool seat. Just put the stool flat on the floor and pull the stool leg vertically. Keep some pressure on the seat at the same time you pull the stool leg. It just come off easily. Hope this will help solve your problem.

Comment: Did this allow the water to drain?

Answer (score 1):

I used a flat head screw driver to pry off the top part of the seat. I emptied the water and put the part back after drying it out

Comment: Oh? Which part to start from? Does it eventually making any mark or loosening the structure after putting back?